# RSpec: How to Stub Only One of Multiple Calls to Same Method

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm having trouble figuring out how to stub only one of two calls to a method. Here's an example:

```
class Example
  def self.foo
    { a: YAML.load_file('a.txt'),   # don't stub - let it load
      b: YAML.load_file('b.txt') }  # stub this one
  end
end

RSpec.describe Example do
  describe '.foo' do
    before do
      allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).with('b.txt').and_return('b_data')
    end

    it 'returns correct hash' do
      expect(described_class.foo).to eq(a: 'a_data', b: 'b_data')
    end
  end
end
```

The test fails because I have stubbed a call to `YAML.load_file` with the args for the second call (`'b.txt'`), not the first one it encounters(`'a.txt'`). I thought argument matching would address this but it does not.

```
Failures:

  1) Example.foo returns correct hash
     Failure/Error:
       { a: YAML.load_file('a.txt'),
         b: YAML.load_file('b.txt') }

       Psych received :load_file with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("b.txt")
              got: ("a.txt")
        Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

Is there a way I can allow the first call to `YAML.load_file` to go through but only stub the second call? How would I do this?

Comment: Ever figure out why `allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).with('b.txt').and_return('b_data')` does not isolate as you'd expect. I had the same expectations and `and_call_original` solved it for me too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a `and_call_original` option (see [rspec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation#%60and-call-original%60-can-configure-a-default-response-that-can-be-overridden-for-specific-args)).

Applied to your example, this should do what you are looking for:

```
before do
  allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).and_call_original
  allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).with('b.txt').and_return('b_data')
end
```